# How to refresh eclipse project programmatically?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp

How could I refresh project programmatically? approach A or B? by the way, My project is not copied to eclipse workspace.will it affect the way of refreshing project?

A

```java
project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, new  org.eclipse.core.runtime.NullProgressMonitor());
```

B

```java
java.io.File file = iFile.getLocation().toFile();
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
fOut.write("Written by FileOutputStream".getBytes());          
iFile.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_ZERO, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible use

```java
iFile.setContents(stream, false, true, progressMonitor);
```

where `stream` is an `InputStream` containing the contents (a `ByteArrayInputStream` for example to write a string). Be careful about the character set of the string - it should match the character set assigned to the file, so:

```java
String string = "Written by FileOutputStream";
byte [] bytes = string.getBytes(iFile.getCharset());
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

Specifying `true` for the third arguments tells Eclipse to maintain the local history for the file. Specify `false` if you don't want this.

Your method 'A' refreshes the whole project which might take more time, 'B' is preferable for a single file.